# biblatex does not print phdthesis

Tags: biblatex

I have the following basic LateX with BibLaTeX to print a categorized bibliography. I have one phdthesis in this simplied self-contained example:

```
\documentclass{article}

% introduce asticks (*) in list of references with new command mybibitem
%\usepackage{cite}
%\newcommand{\mybibitem}[1]{\stepcounter{enumiv} \bibitem[\textbf{*\arabic{enumiv}}]{#1}}  


% BibLaTeX
\usepackage[
  backend=bibtex,
  style=authoryear,
  firstinits=true,
  maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{CV.bib}

\begin{document}

text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text

\nocite{phd2015}

\setlength\bibitemsep{5pt}
\printbibheading[title={Bibliography}]
\printbibliography[type=phdthesis, heading=subbibliography, title={PhD Thesis}]

\end{document}
```

Here my bib file:

```
@PHDTHESIS{phd2015,
  author = {B. Mayer},
  title = {{The Theory of Everything and More}},
  school = {School of Everything, Everything University},
  year = {2015}
}
```

As a result, i get only the header but no phdthesis. The same example works fine for articles and for conference proceedings. Is there something I do wrong with the type phdthesis? Is BibLaTeX somehow expecting something different?

Comment: It should be rather: `type=thesis`. Also note that (standard) `biblatex` seems to expect simply an `@thesis` entry, which is then further subdivided by using the `type` field -- say something like: `type = {Unpublished Ph.D. dissertation},`.

Comment: See section `2.1.2` of the manual, where `@phdthesis` is counted among the (legacy) 'type aliases' as (in this case) an alias for `@thesis`.

Comment: Move his comment to an answer. It worked and I want to reward you. :)

Comment: No problem. Glad it was an easy one.

Comment: why using bibtex and note the modern, more capable, standard, unicode-ready biber?

Comment: Its a thought. I wonder if Overleaf/ShareLatex support that...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The basic solution here is to filter with this: `type=thesis`. So:

```
\printbibliography[type=thesis, heading=subbibliography, title={PhD Thesis}]
```

**Explanation:** According to the manual (section 2.1.2), the entrytype `@phdthesis` is aliased to `@thesis` in `biblatex`. It will automatically provide a note like "PhD Thesis" in the standard styles.  However, it is recommended to use the generic entrytype `@thesis`, which you then disambiguate with the `type` field (e.g., `type = {Unpublished Ph.D. dissertation}`).

Comment: Related after-question: TECHREPORT is officially supported (see section 2.2 in the biblatex manual), but it seems not to work. Any ideas? I should perhaps put it up as another question...

Comment: Please see here; its technically another question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/243800/biblatex-does-not-print-techreport